# Flush left and right in a same equation environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I would like to do something like

```
\begin{align*}
\flushleft A(x) = \\
\flushright B(x) \\
\flushright + C(x)
\end{align*}
```

My problem is to set a nice layout for this long equation, where I have to cut a sum in multiple lines.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment `multline` of package `amsmath` has `\shoveleft` and `\shoveright` for flush right and left:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{multline*}
    % First line is flush left
    A(x) = \\
    % Move to the right, default is centered
   \shoveright{B(x)} \\
    % Last line is flush right
    + C(x)
  \end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Variation

Alignment point is set for the relational operators. The parts left of the less signs are right aligned, the parts right of the alignment point is left aligned:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
    A(x) & \leq \\
    B(x) \\
    {} + C(x) & < 3 \epsilon
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

I'd avoid “flush right”:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
& \biggl|
    \int_{[0,1]^n}
    f\Bigl(\frac{x_1+\dots+x_n}{n}\Bigr)
    \diff x_1 \dots \diff x_n
    -f(1/2)
  \biggr|
\\
&\qquad\le
  \int_{[0,1]^n}
  \biggl|
    (f-p)\Bigl(\frac{x_1+\dots+x_n}{n}\Bigr)
  \biggr|
  \diff x_1 \dots \diff x_n
\\
&\qquad\qquad+\lvert p(1/2)-f(1/2)\rvert\vphantom{\int}
\\
&\qquad\qquad+
  \biggl| 
    \int_{[0,1]^n} 
    p\Bigl(\frac{x_1+\dots+x_n}{n}\Bigr)
    \diff x_1 \dots \diff x_n
    -p(1/2)
  \biggr|
\\
&\qquad<3\varepsilon
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I finally chose your solution but the other answer addresses better the question asked... Thanks!